# How to cook perfect meringue in a gas oven?

Tags: oven, slow-cooking, meringue

The lowest temperature my gas oven goes to is 130C. I have yet to find a gas oven that goes lower than that, which is weird. Is that the case with everyone? I know meringue does better with lower temperatures like 90C, so I was wondering: can one make perfect meringues at 130C, if yes how? Would a fan be of any use?

Comment: Do you live in a hot country? In summer in Iran, my mother used to make meringues in full sun, on the roof.

Comment: @RobinBetts hahahah, yes I do. Lebanon - but it's just too humid for that to work.

Answer (score 2):

I usually go with residual heat.
But I use Pavlova meringue recipe (with teaspoon of potato flour) which call for baking for 30 minutes in 120 degrees (I adjusted time to around 18 minutes to compensate for the 130 temp).
Then I open it a little for around 2 minutes to lower the temp and keep closed for another 2 hours. 
When I was making typical meringue I just put a tray in the oven when the temp dropped to around 100 degrees on gauge (old type gas oven with gauge in the middle of the glass) and just let it sit there for 5-6 hours.

Comment: I will try that method out, but isn't humidity an issue though?

Comment: @user29568 I would say that humidity was good because the temperature was making the outside dry and glazed while the inside was perfectly gooey

Answer (score 0):

When faced with an oven that is slightly too hot, I just prop open the door with a wooden spoon. This allows both heat and humidity out.